# Docker pull on Synology fails when DNS Server is enabled

Tags: ssl, docker, nas, synology

I enabled the DNS server on my Synology. Therefore when I am using the Synology DNS (192.168.1.20) instead of the Google DNS (8.8.8.8), I get this error:

```
me@synology $ sudo docker pull linuxserver/sonarr
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": 
   x509: certificate is valid for synology, not registry-1.docker.io
```

It seems that Docker somehow rewrites the request, but I don't really understand the reason.

Comment: It's telling the certificate is valid for something other than what you're trying to do with it. You need to use a different certificate. Have you searched this error?

Comment: What does your local DNS return for `registry-1.docker.io`?